# Byte Array through Input Stream

Tags: java, arrays, image, sockets, client-server

I am working on client-server sending and receiving of files/images. I use inputstream from a Socket.

Is this code

```
byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
int num = inputStream.read();
sizeAr = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(num).array();
int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();
```

same as this code

```
byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
inputStream.read(sizeAr);
int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();
```

Comment: No, and both are wrong. You are looking for `DataInputStream.readInt()` followed by `readFully()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this code [...] same as this code?

No.

---

The first one does not make much sense to me:

1. allocates a 4 byte array (for no reason?)
2. reads *a single byte* from the stream
3. creates a new 4 byte buffer,

   - puts the byte read in the previous line into the buffer as an int,
   - gets the backing array of the buffer, *replacing the array* in the first line
4. wraps the array from the previous buffer in a new byte buffer,

   - converts it to an int buffer
   - gets the int from this buffer, and assigns this int to `size`

Basically, this is a very convoluted an inefficient way of doing

```
int size = inputStream.read();
```

I don't think this is what you want. :-)

The second one makes more sense:

1. allocates a 4 byte array
2. reads up to 4 bytes from the input stream into the array (note that you should check the return value of `read(byte[])`, to get the number of bytes read, it may be *less* than the size of your array)
3. wraps the array in a buffer,

   - converts it to an int buffer
   - gets the value as an int and assigns it to `size`

This version will read a full 32 bit int value into `size`, which is probably what you want. However, step 2 is not safe, as you may read less than 4 bytes as mentioned.

Probably, a better way would be to use something like:

```
DataInput dataInput = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
int size = dataInput.readInt(); // Will read exactly 4 bytes or throw EOFException
```